# ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST in Asp.Net MVc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, fortify

I scanned my source code with Fortify SCA

I encountered **ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST (API Abuse, Structural)** bug when I checked Fortify report

Fortify found high level bug that say

```
Recommendations:

The following controller action accepts only the POST verb because it has the
[HttpPost]     attribute:


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateWidget(Model model) 
{
// ... controller logic
}
```

But I looked that line of code.It contains

```
[HtttpPost]
```

attribute.

Is it false positive or not?

Answer (score 1):

Fortify SCA itself giving two contrast statements.

ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST (API Abuse, Structural)

Recommendations:

```
The following controller action accepts only the POST verb because it has the
[HttpPost]     attribute:
```

If you are updating model or DB using Model in UpdateWidget method add HttpPost action attribute which is more secure. If you are sure that you've added HttpPost action attribute ignore Fortify bug

Comment: I'm agree with that.
I checked the source code HttpPost attribute is still there.
It looks like Fortify's bug. 

I'm wondering whether there is  any other meaning of this bug or not ?

Comment: I am also getting a false positive, for what it's worth.